# Show that any root $z$ of $z^4+z+3=0$ satisfies $|z|>1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, roots

Show that any root $z$ of $z^4+z+3=0$ satisfies $|z| > 1$

My working is as such:
Let $|z| \leq 1$.
Then consider $|z^4+z| \leq |z^4| + |z| \leq 1 + 1 = 2$.

So, $|z^4 + z| \leq 2$.

Thus $-2 \leq z^4 + z \leq 2$. So $1 \leq z^4+z+3 \leq 5$.

And so $z^4+z+3 \neq 0$.

Hence if $|z| \leq 1$ there is no root $z$, and so any root $z$ must satisfy $|z| < 1$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very close to right. The one bit that is not correct is your claim that  $-2 \le z^4+z \le 2$. It is not correct since $z^4+z$ is complex, and you can't use $\le$ on complex numbers<sup>†</sup>.

But you don't actually need that:

A solution to $z^4 + z +3 = 0$ has $|z^4 + z| = 3$ (add -3 to both sides and take absolute value). 
You've shown that $|z| \le 1 \to |z^4 + z| \le 2$. These contradict, so no solution with $|z| \le 1$ exists.

---

<sup>†</sup> You could argue that since $z$ satisfies $z^4+z=3$, $z^4 + z$ must be real, where $\le$ is valid, but while technically OK, the argument feels a little circular to me.

Comment: thank you so much! what about for a question where its the opposite i.e. it must satisfy |$z$| $\leq$ 1? if i try to do this the same way it doesn't really work since i'd be letting |$z$| > 1 but then i wouldnt be able to use triangle inequality?

Comment: @sam In the cases where the triangle inequality doesn't work for you, you may need heavier machinery like Rouche's theorem that Nosrati refers to in his answer. But it's hard to know without a concrete example.

Comment: Yes i think I can use the circle inequality in this case

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), with $f(z)=z^4+z$ and $g(z)=3$ then on $z=1$ we have
$$|f(z)|=|z^4+z^3|\leq2<3$$
then the number of zeros $z^4+z+3$ and $3$ are the same.